# Cannot access io.micronaut in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

I just wanna share a solution to a problem that I had and cost me 2 hours to solve.

I'm using micronaut 1.3.3 with intellij, and after follow the official guide to create a new app, i had the problem in the Main method saying that the Micronaut.run(Application.class) has a problem, "cannot access Micronaut".

Answer (score -2):

After a few hours i discovered that the gradlew downloaded the "micronaut-runtime" dependency but not injected in the intellij project, so it's necessary to go in "Project Structure" > Modules > Name of Project > Main (in case of have another main out of your project folder just remove it and will work) > in the right panel click in the plus signal in dependencies column > library > find the folder of you micronaut-runtime (you can find easily just pressing ctrl+click in the Micronaut call in Main Method and getting the local address). With this, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. A better idea is to let IntelliJ configure the classpath based on the current state of the project, which it does quite well.  Going into the project settings and adding the libraries yourself is going to be prone to getting the 2 out of sync.  If you locate the Gradle window in your IDE there is a refresh button which will re-evaluate the dependencies in the Gradle build file(s) and will update the project classpath accordingly.

Comment: i tried to do this before the solution above but without success.

Comment: What scope did you express in your Gradle build for this dependency?